# redirect my IE visitors to a different page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer, redirect

I made a site which index.php is a short animated series of texts (not my idea, I advised against it, but I'm not the boss) but anyway, my problem with this animation is that it is not supported by IE and it's not responsive either, so it looks crappy in phones as well.

My question is, does anyone here ever heard of a script or jquery I can use that will sniff the browser (IE > 1, Android, IOs, etc) and redirect them to a home.php within the same site?

Perhaps a PHP script with a header: Location...I don't know, anything.

p.s. I've tried everything I've read in stack overflow and nothing works.

This is the closest I've gotten to any response but not quite what I'm looking for

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var sBrowser, sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;

  if(sUsrAg.indexOf("Chrome") > -1) {
    sBrowser = "Google Chrome";
  } else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
    sBrowser = "Apple Safari";
  } else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Opera") > -1) {
    sBrowser = "Opera";
  } else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
    sBrowser = "Mozilla Firefox";
  } else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("MSIE") > -1) {
    sBrowser = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
  }

  alert("You are using: " + sBrowser);
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: just as a word of advice, IE11 no longer has `MSIE` in the userAgent string

Comment: hmmm, interesting. thank you , I didn't know that. Did they change it to anything else? IE, IE11, ...etc?  ***edit**** I took off MSIE and left a white space and it responded correctly. Alert box said it detected Int Exp in it. I'll try to redirect now with window.location and if it works I'll credit Markasoftware with the answer...But if anyone else have a better, more practical, or more efficient solution, I am open to hear them out.

Comment: possibly better not check browser, but check support animation

Comment: Grundy - I did. But it is all done with PURE CSS and specially those with transitions that are not compatible by IE

Comment: @user32642 use library like moderniz for that

Comment: I have modernizer running already.

Answer (score 0):

You have the browser identification working well, just need to redirect using javascript.

So something along the lines of:

```
var sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;

if(sUsrAg.indexOf("Mobile") > -1) {
    window.location = '/unsupportedpagemobile.html';
} else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("MSIE") > -1) {
    window.location = '/unsupportedpageie.html';
}

</script>
```

Comment: Brian, that was helpful, sorry I couldn't give you a arrow up (not enough rep it said) but anyway, this sorta solved the issue. It is redirecting, yet it redirects regardless of browser being used. I need the page to display in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera

Answer (score 0):

Most CSS animations are handled just fine in modern versions of Internet Explorer. In fact, Internet Explorer supported unprefixed properties before many of its competition. Your CSS animations may not be working in IE due to unbalanced use of vendor prefixes. Are you only targeting things like `-webkit-transition` and `-moz-transition`, forgetting to also include `transition`?

Your animation won't work in earlier versions of Internet Explorer though, unless you polyfill them with jQuery using [`$.fn.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to achieve similar behavior. This may or may not be possible considering the type of animation you're doing - if it's just sliding text around, and fading it in/out, then you could most certainly achieve the same effect for older versions of IE.

Last option would be to create IE-specific [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28vs.85%29.aspx) and place within them a script to relocate the user to an alternative experience. Do not engage in browser sniffing; you're going to send users of IE11 (which can handle your modern experience) away, which makes no sense. Instead, use the features provided by the browsers you wish to target; such as conditional comments.

```html
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <script>
    /*
      In this space we can do one of two things:
        1) Redirect user to an alternative experience with window.location, or
        2) Provide animations via jQuery .animate method.
    */
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```